# Django "Class 'User' has no 'objects' Member" pylint(no-member) [30, 16]

Tags: python-3.x, django, pylint

I'm new to Django, and I got some issue with views.py. I'm not sure why but there is error at User model. I tried to install pylint using `pip install pylint-django` and wrote `{"python.linting.pylintArgs": [ "--load-plugins=pylint_django" ],}` in my vsCode setting. But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

This is my code for models.py and views.py

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from stream_chat import StreamChat

from .models import User

# this decorator marks a view as being exempt from the protection ensured by the middleware
@csrf_exempt

def init(request):
    if not request.body:
        return JsonResponse(status=200, data={'message': 'No request body'})
    body = json.loads(bytes(request.body).decode('utf-8'))

    if 'username' not in body:
        return JsonResponse(status=400, data={'message': 'Username is required to join the channel'})

    username = body['username']
    
    client = StreamChat(api_key=settings.STREAM_API_KEY, 
                        api_secret=settings.STREAM_API_SECRET)
    channel = client.channel('messaging', 'General')

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        token = bytes(client.create_token(
            user_id=user.username)).decode('utf-8')
        return JsonResponse(status=200, data={"username": user.username, 
                                            "token": token, 
                                            "apikey": settings.STREAM_API_KEY})
    
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User(username=username)
        user.save()
        token = bytes(client.create_token(
            user_id=username)).decode('utf-8')
        client.update_users({"id": username, "role": "admin"})
        channel.add_members([username])

        return JsonResponse(status=200, data={"username": user.username, 
                                                "token": token, 
                                                "apiKey": settings.STREAM_API_KEY})
```

Thank you

Comment: Would you add the error please?

Comment: ```tsk@Taesans-MacBook-Pro chat-app % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 /Users/tsk/chat-app/djangoStreamServer/chat/views.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tsk/chat-app/djangoStreamServer/chat/views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .models import User
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package``` this is error message

Comment: Would you please add your project structure as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your import `from .models import User` should be absolute like `from mypackage.models import User`.